# storing data in mysql from submitted html pages

Tags: php, html, mysql, store

So, I am having an issue with referencing the database for storing new user information for my website. Here is an example of the html that we are using. I have also provided the php form as well.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd"
    >
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Log In</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action= "form_process.php" method="post">

//Inputting user information: first name, last name, password, gender.
First Name: <input type="text" name="firstname"> <br/>
Last Name: <input type="text" name="lastname"> <br/>
Password <input type="password" name="password"> <br/>
Are you male or female?<br/>
Male<input type="radio" name="Male" value="Male"> <br/>
Female<input type="radio" name="Female" value="Female"> <br/>
<input type="submit" value="submit"> 
</form> 
</body>
</html>

Here is the php form that I am using to confirm the data passed.

<?php
$first = $_POST['first'];
$last = $_POST['last'];
$email = $_POST['email'];

echo("First: ". $first);
echo("<br/>Last: " . $last);
echo("<br/>Email: " . $email);
?>
```

Let me know how I would be able to store the information to mysql. I am using Go Daddy as the mysql server.

Thank you!

Comment: Have you... God forbid... **tried** anything?

Comment: We are happy to help you solve problems with your existing code, but we will not (in most cases) write the code or development plan for you. You may wish to consult the documentation and/or tutorials to learn the basics of connecting to MySQL via PHP. When you have specific questions about your code during the implementation process, please feel free to post your code and details of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your table is as simple has fields matching what you are collecting via the HTTP POST you would do the following:

```
// open database connection
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=hostname;dbname=dbname', 'username', 'password');

// prepare SQL statement
$sql = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO table (first, last, email) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");

// execute prepared statement and insert into db
$sql->execute(array($first, $last, $email));
```

For a really good beginner tutorial to PDO I would check out: http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers

Comment: Cool! Thank you so much! I'm installing mySql right now. That should be downloaded to use these commands right?

Comment: @EvanWiley Yes sir, you will need MySQL installed / running in order to connect to it an store data. I would suggest trying something like MAMP (Mac) or XAMPP (Windows) if you haven't setup a PHP/MySQL instance before.